# Get C# CGI EXE name in IIS environment

Tags: c#, iis

I'm running a C# console app (compiled with Visual C# 2008) as a CGI application on IIS 6 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.  It serves as a simple API, accepting parameters from the Web and printing HTTP output.

I want to have two available versions, test and live, that use the identical compiled EXE but with different filenames.  So I compile Client.exe, put it on the server, and also copy and rename it to ClientTEST.exe.  At run-time I want to check the EXE name to choose between live and test behaviours.

How can I get the true EXE name in this IIS-launched environment?  I have tried (i) System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess.Name and (ii) System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath.  However, they both give the original name that the EXE was compiled with, and not the name I have renamed it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was an IIS configuration error, not a .NET issue.  Under "Handler Mappings" for the site, *.exe was configured to open the same EXE every time.  So I wasn't seeing Application.StartupPath returning the compile-time EXE name, but rather it was not running the EXE that I thought it was.